# Unable to send Email Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, smtp, sendmail

i m trying to send email It properly working on localhost 
when i live it on server it give me warning
i m using codeigniter here is the code

public function send_me($from,$name,$toEmail,$subject,$msg){

```
    $config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',//user name herer
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxxxxx', //password hre
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap'  => TRUE
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from($from,$name);
    $this->email->to($toEmail);//to address here
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($msg);
    if($this->email->send())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and warning are

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection timed out)

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1689
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1846

Comment: use $this->email->initialize($config); instead of passing it while loading

Comment: can you explain this raheel shan

Comment: simpledo therse steps $this->load->library('email'); then $this->email->initialize($config); because it produces problem while loading and passing togather

Comment: take a look here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: on local it working  when i live it it give the same error of the question

Comment: Is OpenSSL installed on your live server? You'll need it if you use the `ssl://`prefix. You can find out by running `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have answered several issues like this one. If your local email is working fine then follow the steps below:

To use Google SMTP in CodeIgniter you need to make 2 (two) changes into your Gmail account setting: *(N.B. Please be aware that it is now easier for an attacker to break into your account -says Google)*

> 1. Set off **2-step Verification**.
> 2. **Allow less secure apps**: ON (or Enable)

Now use `'smtp_host'` as `ssl://smtp.gmail.com` instead of `smtp.googlemail.com`

Hope upcoming users can get this help too.

Comment: try to vary your answers not cut and paste the same from 2 answers of yours without regard to OP particulars

Comment: I am new in SO. I got a lot of solution here, so I decided to contribute my experience in SO regularly. I will remember your suggestion.